# Most secure way to pass Laravel passport access_token from Laravel blade to React component

Tags: reactjs, laravel, security, laravel-echo

I'm building chat application with ReactJS and Laravel, we are using Laravel Echo.
API needs an access_token to be authenticated so we need to pass the access_token in the component.

How can do it securely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access_token can be generated by Laravel Passport (LP). Since LP is just an integration into The PHP League's OAuth 2, JSON Web Tokens (JWT) are issued by default. These tokens are pretty safe to be stored on the client side.

If you check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#personal-access-tokens), you will be able to generate tokens for users without going through the normal OAuth 2 flow.

Using the browser's [LocalStorage](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwim45WDhuTeAhWSbsAKHZ3ABrUQFjALegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FWindow%2FlocalStorage&usg=AOvVaw2AmRi2if_HfOObD3GES5FE), you can then store this token for future use.

Answer (score 0):

The backend should have all api keys. Assume that anything sent to frontend can and will be copied to use elsewhere.

I strongly suggest that you use JWT (json web tokens) to handle authentication and make all such api calls on the backend on behalf of the authenticated user. Ideally checking if the user has permissions to do so.